# How to invoke servlet from swt?

Tags: java, servlets, swt

The servlet can be invoked when button is clicked from UI which calls ajax/javascript code with url "/Servlet".
I have to do the same functionality with swt on button click. Is it possible to call servlet with swt button click? If yes, then how to do this? Please provide code example.

Note:- I have tried the below

```
URL url = new URL("/Servlet");    
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
```

But it is giving this error:

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /Servlet
```

Comment: Focus on writing the Java to correctly invoke your Servlet. Then it's not harder than doing anything else with a SWT Button.

Comment: "/Servlet" is not a complete URL, probably it is a partial one. But as the `URL` class is not given a base URL relative to which to interpret that partial URL, the constructor can merely give up.

Answer (score 0):

add 'http://' or 'https' in front of your url
for example
'http://www.baidu.com'

Comment: In web.xml, servlet mapping is given as <url-pattern>/Servlet</url-pattern>.
I do not have to call any website, I am just calling servlet.

Comment: @VishalSharnagat When you use a web.xml you are writing a web application. SWT is not a web application and you will have to do a lot more work to call servlets.

Comment: use "http://127.0.0.1//{webroot}/Servlet".replace {webroot} as your real web root.